# Angular 8: Combine two independent apps into one

Tags: angular, templates, e-commerce, admin, angular8

am a beginner in Angular. I am developing an application and decided to use Angular Multikart ecommerce template. It has a front-end and admin-end separately. I am able to load and run each one in Visual code separately. But I want to create an application with front-end  and admin-end in one. How do I merge the two?

Comment: Why do you need to merge the front-end and admin-end. They are two different applications.

Comment: because they will be sharing resources. For instance the assets folder will be same. This is a multivendor application meaning each vendor will have a backend. How then will they share uploaded images  if they are 2 different apps? Assist me if am lost

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you have two Angular applications, one for clients and one for admins, and you want to have only one, right?.

Comment: I didn't really look into the Multikart ecommerce template. But, if the there are two different applications for front-end and admin-end. you don't need to merge them. you just need to share the resources and data.

Comment: yes. That is how I want it. I am developing from my computer's local enviroment

Comment: @Swinkaran do you have a link on how to do that?

Comment: All you need to do is to change the application settings/configuration settings, so that both the application are pointing to same resource, e.g. both are pointing to one database, one folder location. Then you run both the applications.

Comment: I will try that .I have minimal experience since this is my first real world project in angular.

Comment: I have no link. But, generally in Angular, you can find the file appsettings.json which has settings like connection string. But, sorry mate, it is hard to give you concrete answers without looking at the templates / source. If you are new to Angular, Look at these before start working on templates, https://angular.io/tutorial , https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operations-with-aspnet-core-using-angular-5-a

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two project with in one folder then you have to follow the Angular Workspace project folder structure.
even In Angular Workspace you will be able to create multiple angular application using `ng` command and even you will be able to share your resources and assets with multiple projects.

Comment: will I run ng serve separately for each app? If so how then will admin and front end apps communicate: since each will require server to run separately

Comment: yes you will run ng serve separately for each app. and 
In Angular workspace you will able to create shared Library like a common place for code. and you can use that common shared library in each project.

Comment: Thankyou . Still on this if I have multiple apps in one folder and deploy them as one, will they install in mobile app as one app or two?

Comment: Hello! In Angular workspace project will build separately in `dist` folder and you will able to deploy each and every project separately.